# Tricks to speed up excel - matlab import and export of the calculation to excel

Tags: performance, matlab, import, export

I use the import function of matlab to get excel data in matlab, and i have roughly 400x30000 cells, that is 12Mio cells to process. i import mixed information, so i have text and numbers in various length, but assuming every bit of that has 10 characters, and here comes the question:

How long should that action take roughly with a Intel Core i5 CPU 750@2.67 GHz with 4 GB RAM and 64 bit system running 32bit matlab? Roughly please, but certainly not one hour, right?

so, perhaps i might want to trim my data (places after the comma) in the excel file before importing? what else tricks do you know to load basically the same information into matlab? I never had this issue but am in dire need for common tricks to speed things up.

on the same note, i am using files which i access via structures, and the result should be returned into the same excel file. Now i have realized that it is this process which makes my code run mostly over night. How do you deal with exporting files?

Comment: Have you explored using `csv` files instead? Would that be feasible for reading and writing for your case?

Comment: I was hoping i might avoid csv because of the limited function to edit my data. I might turn my excel every time into csv though when im done editing it, generating yet another file which might be messed up before going to matlab. whats the advantage of csv in computation speed, any rough estimates on that?

Comment: Must be faster, but not sure by how much. Haven't done any benchmarking on that. But you could try it out with relatively smaller datasize?